# SourceSafe reporting - how to get custom reports in a usable format?

Tags: reporting, visual-sourcesafe

I'm hoping that i'm simply missing something, but I really can't see how to get the report I want out of SourceSafe.

All I need is a report of the check-ins and corresponding comments for a particular date range. So, for example, I can see who has checked in what in the past month and what they said about the check-in.

I wouldn't imagine it would be too much to ask but it possibly is... I've seen a couple of 3rd party VSS reporting tools about but most of these seem to only support up to v6 and we're on v8, which suggests to me that possibly v8 has more reporting options that I simply can't find!

Can anyone lend any assistance? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this by:

- Right click on the source safe  directory (project) and choose "Show history"
- In the dialog you can specify a date range
- In the history dialog that appears press "report"
- In the report dialog check "include details". Now you can generate the report.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: That's cool Dani, so +1 for that, cheers!  Now it's just on to the 'usable' part of the question... ;) 

Is there any way to output that as CSV or anything that's a bit more organised than a big long list?  I guess I could write something to parse it but ideally that won't be necessary!

Comment: There is nothing I know about. I don't think you can get a different format, but you never know, maybe someone will correct me. Generally speaking, "usable" and Visual Source Safe is not a good match ;).

Comment: Haha! How very true.  The general consensus does seem to be along the lines of "use anything but"!

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution using Visual Studio Regular Expressions:

1RST PASS
vs2005 matches 20 characters at begining of each line.
Find what:{^....................} .*$

replaces what you found, and truncates the rest of each line.
Replace with:\1

2ND PASS
multi-line matching and replacing
Find what: (\n:b)

replace by joining all lines that start with a blank, and remove the blank
Replace with: LEAVE BLANK